# Filter list items using custom field type in REST API

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, custom-field-types

I have a custom field type created by inheriting default **SPFieldLookup** type field.

I have a SharePoint custom list with these type of fields. I want to fetch list items from this list using REST API. I want to get data from list using REST API and filter it using these custom field type columns.

I have tried below URL for that but it's not working:

```
http://<SITE_URL>/_api/web/lists(guid'bf3bf2d7-e352-456a-98b2-a6738e44390f')/items?$select=ID,Title&$filter=Country%20eq%20%27INDIA%27
```

Here, **Country** is the column with custom field type.

It seems custom field type columns are not working with REST API.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Lookup-fields are objects that have properties. If your Country-lookup has a returned field called Title, you must `expand` it and include the field in the `select`. Your query would look something like this:

```
http://<SITE_URL>/_api/web/lists(guid'bf3bf2d7-e352-456a-98b2-a6738e44390f')/items?$select=ID,Title,Country/Title&$expand=Country&$filter=Country/Title%20eq%20%27INDIA%27
```

Comment: It will work with OOTB lookup type column. I have created "Country" column with custom field type( for example: this type of field : http://www.boostsolutions.com/cascaded-lookup.html) And I want to filter on this type of column.

Comment: Is this on an older version of SharePoint? I'm not really sure custom fields are supported anymore, the last i can find of any documentation relates to SP 2007 / 2010. You may have more success with JSOM or CSOM to obtain the field value, i wouldn't honestly get my hopes up though.

Are you sure your business requirement cannot be solved by simply using standard SharePoint fields? Most logic (such as the cascading) can easily be constructed by using a front-end code snippet using for instance jQuery.